# For SQLite3 databases is there any database Metadata that gets lost during dump & regenerate operation?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

If I dump a sqlite3 database `db1.db` using the following commands:

```
sqlite3 db1.db
.output temp.sql
.dump
.exit
```

I then regenerate it as db2.db using the following commands:

```
sqlite3 -init temp.sql db2.db
.exit
```

***My Question: The table content for `db1.db` and `db2.db` are the same but do I lose any versioning information or metadata as a result of this process?***

Answer (score 0):

".dump" output includes the SQL commands to create the table(s) and related index(es).
The 2 meta tables are sqlite_master and sqlite_stat1 table.
If you have performed an Analyze on the database, that information wont be present in the .dump

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "performed an Analyze" on the database. Is there a way to export sqlite_master and sqlite_stat1 tables for import back into a Database created with the dump file. Thanks.